# Prevent an arithmetic operator from immediately following another one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a calculator script which currently allows me to type invalid input values like 5*****5. Such inputs (where one arithmetic operator like `*`, `+` etc immediately follows another) should be restricted because they make no sense. How can I modify my code to restrict such inputs?

```js
function c(val) {
  var1 = $("#bar").val(val);
}

function v(val) {
  var2 = $("#bar").val($("#bar").val() + val);
}

function equal() {
  var3 = c(eval($("#bar").val()));
}

function reset() {
  var4 = $("#bar").val("");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#backspace").click(function() {
    var barValue = $("#bar").val();
    $("#bar").val(barValue.substring(0, barValue.length - 1));
  });
});
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="text" id="bar" size="15" readonly>
  <input type="button" value="C" onclick="reset('')">
</p>
<p>
  <input type="button" value="←" id="backspace">
  <input type="button" value="­" onclick="">
  <input type="button" value="­" onclick="">
  <input type="button" value="­" onclick="">
  <input type="button" value="­" onclick="">
</p>
<p>
  <input type="button" value="7" onclick="v('7')">
  <input type="button" value="8" onclick="v('8')">
  <input type="button" value="9" onclick="v('9')">
  <input type="button" value="/" onclick="v('/')">
  <input type="button" value="­" onclick="">
</p>
<p>
  <input type="button" value="4" onclick="v('4')">
  <input type="button" value="5" onclick="v('5')">
  <input type="button" value="6" onclick="v('6')">
  <input type="button" value="*" onclick="v('*')">
  <input type="button" value="­" onclick="">
</p>
<p>
  <input type="button" value="1" onclick="v('1')">
  <input type="button" value="2" onclick="v('2')">
  <input type="button" value="3" onclick="v('3')">
  <input type="button" value="-" onclick="v('-')">
  <input type="button" value="­" onclick="">
</p>
<p>
  <input type="button" value="0" onclick="v('0')">
  <input type="button" value="." onclick="v('.')">
  <input type="button" value="+" onclick="v('+')">
  <input type="button" value="=" onclick="equal()" id="equal">
  <input type="button" value="­" onclick="">
</p>
<div id="history"></div>
```

Here is a **[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/xkefarx4/)** to the full source.

Comment: I have bugs in my code, how to prevent double + or something like that bugs in my calculator? If you don't know what I want, I'll explain everything (sorry for my bad english) my calculator has bugs, if I write this 5**13 it mustn't work, I mean correct must be like that 5*13

Comment: Could you explain what is the difference between this and [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30841953/i-have-bugs-in-my-code-how-to-prevent-double-or-something-like-that-bugs-in-m)?

Comment: jsfiddle is working there :)

Comment: If you are just adding a JSFiddle, please edit your existing question instead of asking a new one. Also, you shouldn't accept the answer if it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: i don't know how to use this site. please tell me how to prevent this bugs

Comment: Get help from **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/RzeRS/7/)**

Comment: I have reworded the title and content to better explain your actual problem and have also created a snippet based on the source code from your Fiddle. You can always use the snippet option to add your code instead of/in addition to Fiddle. If you feel the code is too lengthy then you can use use the "Hide Snippet" option to collapse it by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regular expressions. Test to see if last value is +,-,*,or /

If the lastChar matches this criteria and so does the passed value do not do anything.

```
function v(val) {
    var patt = /\+|\-|\*|\//
    var barValue = $("#bar").val();
    var lastChar = barValue.substring(barValue.length, barValue.length - 1);
    if (patt.test(lastChar) && patt.test(val)) {
        //do nothing as current val and lastChar are mathematical characters
    } else {
        //update the formula
        var2 = $("#bar").val($("#bar").val() + val);
    }
}
```